# How to replace index number in data worksheet with lookup information in another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, replace

My data worksheet ("Sh1") shows information with index number in column C.
e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4.

I have another worksheet ("Sh2") to identify what each number means.
e.g.
Cell A1: 1
Cell B1: manufacturing

How to replace the number in column C of Sh1 with information from column B of Sh2?

This is what I have

```vb
'Add information in data form
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
   Dim NextRow As Long, Lastrow As Long
   
   Lastrow = Sheets("CustomerMaster").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   
   NextRow = Lastrow + 1
   
   'If formValidation = True Then

        Sheets("CustomerMaster").Cells(NextRow, 1) = Sheets("Customer Master Data Entry").TextID
        Sheets("CustomerMaster").Cells(NextRow, 2) = Sheets("Customer Master Data Entry").TextCompany
        Sheets("CustomerMaster").Cells(NextRow, 3) = Sheets("Customer Master Data Entry").DropDowns("Drop Down 8").Value
        Sheets("CustomerMaster").Cells(NextRow, 4) = Sheets("Customer Master Data Entry").TextRevenue
        Sheets("CustomerMaster").Cells(NextRow, 5) = Sheets("Customer Master Data Entry").TextAddress
        Sheets("CustomerMaster").Cells(NextRow, 6) = DropDowns("Drop Down 11").Value
        Sheets("CustomerMaster").Cells(NextRow, 7) = Sheets("Customer Master Data Entry").TextInitialCust
        Sheets("CustomerMaster").Cells(NextRow, 8) = Sheets("Customer Master Data Entry").TextSource
        Sheets("CustomerMaster").Cells(NextRow, 9) = Sheets("Customer Master Data Entry").TextEntered
        Sheets("CustomerMaster").Cells(NextRow, 10) = DropDowns("Drop Down 21").Value
        Sheets("CustomerMaster").Cells(NextRow, 11) = Sheets("Customer Master Data Entry").TextRemarkCust
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a double loop should work, please try the following :)

```
Option Explicit
Sub trial()

'worksheets variables
Dim wsh1 As Worksheet: Set wsh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim wsh2 As Worksheet: Set wsh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

Dim lastRow1 As Long
lastRow1 = wsh1.Range("C" & wsh1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim lastRow2 As Long
lastRow2 = wsh2.Range("A" & wsh2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Loop wsh1
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To lastRow1
    Dim j As Long
    'Loop wsh2
    For j = 1 To lastRow2
        If wsh1.Cells(i, 3).Value = wsh2.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            wsh1.Cells(i, 3).Value = wsh2.Cells(j, 2).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I also added code that I wrote. I'm very new to this. Could you help me specifically where should I revise.

Comment: Just replace your code with  the code above and should work in the workbook where the two worksheets are.

Answer (score 0):

### Replace Indexes With Values

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- It is assumed that only numbers (indexes) will be considered in Source Lookup Column Range (Source First Column Range). They do not have to be sorted.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub replaceIndexes()
    
    ' Constants
    
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const srcCols As String = "A:B"
    Const srcFirstRow As Long = 1
    ' Destination
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dstFirstCell As String = "C1"
    ' Other
    Const Delimiter As String = ", "
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.

    ' Declare a range variable.
    Dim rng As Range
    
    ' Source
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet.
    With wb.Worksheets(srcName)
        ' Attempt to define Source Range.
        Set rng = defineNonEmptyRange(.Columns(srcCols).Rows(srcFirstRow))
    End With
    ' Validate Source Range.
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Define Source Array.
    Dim Source As Variant: ReDim Source(1 To rng.Columns.Count)
    ' Declare a counter variable.
    Dim n As Long
    ' Loop through columns of Source Range (or, of arrays of Source Array).
    For n = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        ' Write values from current column of Source Range to current
        ' element (array) of Source Array.
        Source(n) = getColumnRange(rng, n)
    Next n
    ' Reset range variable.
    Set rng = Nothing
    
    ' Destination
    
    ' Define Destination Worksheet.
    With wb.Worksheets(dstName)
        ' Attempt to define Destination Range.
        Set rng = defineNonEmptyRange(.Range(dstFirstCell))
    End With
    ' Validate Destination Range.
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Write values from Destination Range to Destination Array.
    Dim Dest As Variant: Dest = getColumnRange(rng)
    
    ' Result
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim cValue As Variant ' Current Destination Value
    Dim cArray As Variant ' Current Array of Values
    Dim cVal As Variant ' Current Value in Array of Values
    Dim cMatch As Variant ' Current Match
    Dim i As Long ' Destination Rows Counter
    
    ' Loop through rows of Destination Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(Dest, 1)
        ' Write value of current element in Destination array to variable.
        cValue = Dest(i, 1)
        ' Test for error value...
        If Not IsError(cValue) Then
            ' Test for empty value...
            If Not IsEmpty(cValue) Then
                ' Split Current Destination Value to Current Array of Values.
                cArray = Split(cValue, Delimiter)
                ' Loop through elements of Current Array of Values.
                For n = 0 To UBound(cArray)
                    cVal = cArray(n)
                    On Error Resume Next
                    cVal = CLng(cVal)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If IsNumeric(cVal) Then
                        ' Attempt to find a match in Source Lookup Array.
                        cMatch = Application.Match(cVal, Source(1), 0)
                        ' Test it found...
                        If IsNumeric(cMatch) Then
                            ' Write matching element from
                            ' Source Result Array to current element
                            ' in Current Array of Values.
                            cArray(n) = Source(2)(cMatch, 1)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next n
                ' Replace current element in Destination Array
                ' with joined elements of Current Array of Values.
                Dest(i, 1) = Join(cArray, Delimiter)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Write values from Destination Array to destination range.
    rng.Value = Dest
    
End Sub


Function defineNonEmptyRange( _
    FirstRowRange As Range) _
As Range
    ' Validate First Row Range.
    If Not FirstRowRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim cel As Range
        With FirstRowRange
            ' Attempt to define Last Non-Empty Cell Range.
            Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Find( _
                What:="*", _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            ' Validate Last Non-Empty Cell Range.
            If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                ' Define Non-Empty Range.
                Set defineNonEmptyRange = .Resize(cel.Row - .Row + 1)
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function

Function getColumnRange( _
    SourceRange As Range, _
    Optional ByVal nthColumn As Long = 1) _
As Variant
    If Not SourceRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim Data As Variant
        With SourceRange.Columns(nthColumn)
            If .Cells.Count > 1 Then
                Data = .Value
            Else
                ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
                Data(1, 1) = .Value
            End If
        End With
        getColumnRange = Data
    End If
End Function
```